Kafka Streams with thread-based parallelism vs Kafka Parallel Consumers for parallel processing
We are building event-driven architecture for a live collaborative form. Our solution uses Kafka as the event broker, where event ordering and stateful stream processing are critical requirements. We are expecting around 5000 active forms at any given time, with a peak load of approximately 10,000 events per second.
Problem:
Fields in the form are interlinked, so changes in one field may affect others which has to be auto populated. The application processes both small and large events, each with distinct processing times
Example
Small events (Single field changes in the form): Takes around 150ms to process
Large events (Upload the complete form data using an Excel file): Takes around 7s to process(To autopopulate some fields we might have to do DB lookup)
Our streaming application must handle processing for both types of events in a non-blocking way. That is, if a large event of one form is uploaded to a partition, it should not block the processing of events from another form in that partition.
Proposed Solutions and Challenges:

Dedicated Partitions for Each Form: Assigning 5000 partitions for 5000 forms, processed by Kafka Streams with thread-based parallelism (e.g., To process the events of 5000 forms we would require roughly 600 octa-core servers for parallel processing)Cons: This approach significantly increases partition reassignment time with higher partition counts.
Using Kafka Parallel Consumers: Assigning (no of forms/no of threads) 5000/8 = ~600 partitions across 600 octa core instances allows each partition to handle events for 8 forms. But parallel consumers lacks features like stateful stream processing.

The problem in both these approaches is that spinning up 600 instances is way expensive for a  startup but we also don't want the compromise on performance of our web app.
Architecture:

When the browser-1 changes a field in the form through the web socket server the event reaches the kafka "form data" topic. A streaming application enriches the event and produces the data back to the "enriched form data" topic. A kafka connect application takes the data from the "enriched form data" topic publishes it to redis pub sub from where the web socket servers receive the event and forward it to the browsers.
To enrich the events generated by the user we have to traverse through a graph do DB lookup if the graph node requires and then do some calcualtion for every graph node.
If this is the case, we will not be able to use Stream-table joins(instead of DB lookups).



You're using an async message queue... Why would web app performance suffer? Don't run Kafka or the clients in the http app server. Easy. 2. Who says you must have 600 processes / instances? Who said there needs to be one consumer per instance? Have you tried benchmarking your hardware? I suspect that consuming 8 partitions will not saturate a 1Gbps network interface 3. Assuming one form-events topic, why is there one partition per form? Two forms can easily share a partition, what's the purpose of separation and what if you add just one more form, or even deprecate one?


What is your question? You seem to have forgotten to ask one.

@TylerH  I wanted to know whether the proposed solution for the problem is right? If it is right, then it seems to be expensive. So I wanted to know, whether there were any alternative solution for the problem

tl;dr - Remove remote database calls and file processing. Libraries don't matter, as both can accomplish what you're trying to do without the number of instances you're proposing

There seems to be a misunderstanding that threads must equal cores. This might be true for absolute performance, but 10K events per second could easily be done on much less

should not block the processing of events from another form in that partition

That's the whole purpose of multi-threading  and/or partitioning. Multi-processing is just an added benefit.

Upload the complete form data using an Excel file

Your forms, I assume have a well defined structure that could be key value pairs? I.e, the html element id mapped to string, number, boolean, arrays, etc? If so, that's what you should be focusing on improving. If the forms generate excel files, they could also generate a format that's more friendly to Kafka processing (e.g. Msgpack, Protobuf, Avro).
Do that with kafka compression enabled, then you might as well have all events be a "large event" rather than individual deltas. It'll make processing logic much simpler as you can just upsert a whole payload at once rather than lookup by id, ensure that changed field still exists, then update that one field, etc.

To autopopulate some fields we might have to do DB lookup

Use CDC. Convert table to stream, then do table lookups natively in Kafka with Stream-table joins.

Some Clarifications: 1. You're using an async message queue. Why would web app performance suffer -> I have update the architecture 2. Do table lookups natively in Kafka with Stream-table joins -> We have to traverse through a graph then do DB lookup. Guess using Stream-table joins will be difficult 3. The user instead of entering each and every field might upload an excel which has the form data. we have to process it in a non blocking way.


Kafka can handle Graphs. 3) You can process in non blocking way with threads or async file readers. Use callbacks when the processing has completed. Or handle processing client side before sending to Kafka, as mentioned

